# 2D array in YAML

Tags: arrays, yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I've a helm chart with attribute 2darrayIPs. This attribute takes value from values.yaml file which inturn is given via helm installation command

helm-chart/templates/main.yaml

```
2darrayIPs: {{ .Values.2darrayIPs }}
```

helm-chart/values.yaml

```
2darrayIPs: [[]]  -- empty array, this value is given via installation command
```

I'm passing 2d array via helm command while installing helm chart.

```
helm install ..... -f val.yaml
```

val.yaml

```
2darrayIPs:
  - - 1.1.1.1
    - 2.2.2.2
  - - 3.3.3.3
    - 4.4.4.4
```

I'm getting this error while installing helm chart:

```
Error: YAML parse error on templates/main.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: did not find expected ',' or ']'
```

If I give one array as given below, the installation is successful but in my logs I get a single array with only one value instead of two:

`[[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]]`

val.yaml

```
2darrayIPs:
  - - 1.1.1.1
    - 2.2.2.2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your templates are trying to write out something more complex than a simple string, the default `{{ .Values.name }}` serialization is something Go-native that's not especially useful.  Helm includes a [`toJson`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) template function, and also an undocumented `toYaml`, which can write these out in more useful formats.

```yaml
# as an array of arrays, in JSON syntax
2darrayIPs: {{ .Values.2darrayIPs | toJson }}
```

```yaml
# as an array of arrays, in expanded YAML syntax
# (identical to the previous, but `helm template` output will be
# easier to read)
2darrayIPs: {{- .Values.2darrayIPs | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

```yaml
# as a YAML-encoded string; for example in a ConfigMap
2darrayIPs: |-
{{ .Values.2darrayIPs | toYaml | indent 2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid yaml. If possible, you should raise an issue on the repository of the yaml parser used here. In the meantime, Yaml is a superset of JSON, so you can use plain JSON 2D arrays:

```yaml
2darrayIPs: [["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2"]]
```

Comment: Its the same issue with giving one array, it takes both values as one value in array. I will look to see if there is any issue with yaml parser. Thanks!